# How to make a function do a random event over and over

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

What I mean is when I declare a function like

```
import turtle
import random
turt = turtle.Turtle()
x = random.randint(-300,300)
y = random.randint(-300,300)
def randomspot():
    turt.penup()
    turt.goto(x,y)
    turt.pendown()
```

and declear the function twice, it goes to the same spot. What should I do?

Comment: You need to set `x` and `y` inside the function, so they change every time you call the function. You're just setting them once, and using those same values every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import turtle
import random
turt = turtle.Turtle()

def randomspot():
    turt.penup()
    turt.goto(
      random.randint(-300,300),
      random.randint(-300,300)
    )
    turt.pendown()
```

you need to create a new random number every time you run the function, before you were defining x and y then running the same function. x and y never have a chance to change.